# Checking luggage for minor I'm not traveling with

Tags: usa, luggage, minors, domestic-travel

My parents are flying through my local airport and my 5 year old daughter is joining them on their journey from there.  My parents and daughter have their itineraries "connected".

I'll be checking her in and checking her baggage.  As I thought about it though, I realized this might be a weird situation.  I'd imagine there are two fairly normal situations:

1. Unaccompanied minor
2. Accompanied minor with an adult on the same itinerary.

However, I'm not sure my situation (accompanied minor without the adult on the same itinerary) matches those exactly.

Will I have any trouble checking baggage in this situation?

Comment: Have you called your airline to see what they say? I would also make sure your parent(s) will exit the secure area, pick up your daughter, and go through security again. I sure wouldn't want to send a 5 year old through security by herself!

Comment: @Greg My understanding is I'll be able to escort her through security.  Ideally the grandparents don't leave the secure area.  I could contact the airline, but I find the prospect daunting.  Besides it can't possibly be nearly as fun as the SE network.

Comment: If you say which airline she's flying, somebody else here might be keen enough to call them in order to provide an answer. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill It's Alaska Airlines if there are any sadist out there.

Comment: @MikeH be aware that you will not be entitled to go through security with your child just because she is a child. You will  need a gate pass for that. Alaska Airlines call them escort passes, which you should get from the ticket counter, but that probably means your child needs to be booked as an UM for the flight (the same will probably apply for check-in anyway).

Comment: Note that Alaska explicitly states that you have to call them in this situation (or a situation very close to this one): “If a friend or family member will be meeting the child passenger(s) in a connecting city, you must call Alaska Airlines reservations at 1-800-252-7522 (TTY: Dial 711 for Relay Services) , prior to travel.” (from https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/policies/children-traveling-alone/unaccompanied-minor-booking)

Comment: Also, provide a covering letter explaining to airline, security etc that your daughter is travelling with her grandparents with your permission. Provide your contact details and attach a copy of your ID card/passport. I'm not sure what jurisdiction you are in, but in the UK (for instance) S. 55 of the Borders, Citizenship and Immigration Act 2009 places a 'duty of care' on Border Force officers in respect of children travelling to/from UK.

Comment: @jcaron That's pretty much an answer; you may as well make it one.

Comment: @jcaron I'm with Michael Hampton on that one.  That exactly answers my question.

Comment: @jcaron want to make it an answer? Looks like it's popular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alaska explicitly [states](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/policies/children-traveling-alone/unaccompanied-minor-booking) that you have to call them in this situation (or a situation very close to this one):

> If a friend or family member will be meeting the child passenger(s) in a connecting city, you must call Alaska Airlines reservations at 1-800-252-7522 (TTY: Dial 711 for Relay Services), prior to travel.

Comment: Way to resurrect your activity from the dead :)